# Fetching time entries from Freckle API

Tags: c#, api

I want to get time entries of Freckle using its API for some specific dates,  but either I get 404 - Not Found and when I change the formation of URL it generates 406 - Not Acceptable. **And when I want to access them without using the date filter It works fine**. The URI I am sending for date filter is:

```
        string dFilter = @"\ -data'search[from]=2012-07-05'";
        string uri = @"https://apitest.letsfreckle.com/api/entries.xml"+dFilter;
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("X-FreckleToken:lx3gi6pxdjtjn57afp8c2bv1me7g89j");
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        responseXML = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

can you tell me how to use this date Filter correctly? The Documentation of API can be found at:
[Documentation](http://madrobby.github.com/freckle-apidocs/entries.html)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're including the filter in the URL using a space and command line options which are part of a `curl` command.

The documentation shows things like:

```
curl -G -H "[stuff]" https://apitest.letsfreckle.com/api/entries.xml \
  -d 'search[from]=2009-10-10'
```

There the `\` is a line continuation, and `-d` is used to pass data for the request. The quotes are just to keep it all in one parameter for the shell. The `-G` says to still use a `GET` request though, and put the data in the URL... but it's not quite as you've done it. Try this:

```
string filter = "search[from]=2012-07-05";
string uri = @"https://apitest.letsfreckle.com/api/entries.xml?" + filter;
```

(Also note that you ought to use a `using` statement for the `WebResponse` and the `StreamReader`.)

Comment: so can you tell me how can I use it?